# How to edit the Samsung Trailer Tag "Timestamp"

Tags: timestamp, metadata, jpeg, exiftool, samsung

I have an image of which i'd like to modify the timestamp. The problem being that it is a samsung trailer tag and can't be modified with exiftool. Does anyone know of another tool that could do this?
Thank you for reading.

Comment: There really isn't much of a reason to need to change this data.  It will not be read by any programs other than exiftool and probably exiv2.

Answer (score 1):

Exiftool cannot change the Samsung Trailer Tag however if you need to change it you need to open the image(file) in a hex editor and find what values need to be changed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the option suggested by @Ryan_Kinakr, editing the `Samsung:TimeStamp` tag should not be difficult to do in a hex editor. Make sure to use it on a test file, as I have not actually tested this to verify it works.

If you look at the file using exiftool's [`-v3` (`-verbose3`) option](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#v-NUM--verbose), you will see output similar to this for the Samsung trailer.

```
  SamsungTrailer_0x0a01Name = Image_UTC_Data
  - Tag '0x0a01-name' (14 bytes):
    3c8a6b: 49 6d 61 67 65 5f 55 54 43 5f 44 61 74 61       [Image_UTC_Data]
  TimeStamp = 1704333346492
  - Tag '0x0a01' (13 bytes):
    3c8a79: 31 37 30 34 33 33 33 33 34 36 34 39 32          [1704333346492]
  SamsungTrailer_0x0aa1Name = MCC_Data
  - Tag '0x0aa1-name' (8 bytes):
    3c8a8e: 4d 43 43 5f 44 61 74 61                         [MCC_Data]
  MCCData = 310
  - Tag '0x0aa1' (3 bytes):
    3c8a96: 33 31 30                                        [310]
  SamsungTrailer_0x0c61Name = Camera_Capture_Mode_Info
  - Tag '0x0c61-name' (24 bytes):
    3c8aa1: 43 61 6d 65 72 61 5f 43 61 70 74 75 72 65 5f 4d [Camera_Capture_M]
    3c8ab1: 6f 64 65 5f 49 6e 66 6f                         [ode_Info]
  SamsungTrailer_0x0c61 = 1
  - Tag '0x0c61' (1 bytes):
    3c8ab9: 31
```

The part to edit would be the `[Image_UTC_Data]` section.  The thirteen bytes that make up the `TimeStamp` tag is simply the Unix time stamp for the set time.  To edit it, you would need to figure out the Unix time stamp for the date/time you want to change it to, and overwrite that section with the new time stamp.

Note that when exiftool reads this tag, it converts it to the local time zone, so you will not be able to change the time zone that exiftool outputs. That value will always depend upon the locale set by the computer you are using.